# Database solution for online dictionary

Tags: database-design

I'm seeking advice concerning a database solution for an online dictionary.

I'm a front-end developer with very little experience with databases.

I have a JSON file with around 1.5 million lines of code and I've tried to find somewhere to do a bulk import of it.

So far, I've tried Backend as a service and headless CMS solutions such as Firebase and Strapi respectively but I haven't found an easy enough way to do a bulk import.

Should I look for another backend service? Perhaps Headless WordPress to do a bulk import?

Or, self host my own database? Which would then require me to learn a backend language as well as a database?

If so, would MySQL or NoSQL be the more suitable option?

Could somebody point me in the right direction please.

Thank you

Comment: You're asking a DB forum if you should use a DB or not? (I believe WordPress uses a DB under the hood.) Also,  this seems like a "list of software" question; which are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, unfortunately shopping list questions and most opinionated questions are off-topic here, so your post will likely be closed.

But storing all of your data in a single 1.5 million line JSON file sounds inefficient and difficult to manage, so you should definitely use some kind of database for your data.

Picking a relational database (like MySQL) or a NoSQL database depends on things like:

1. If your data is structured (e.g. you have concrete objects in your application that represent the data).
2. How quickly does the structure change?
3. Do you want to manage those changes at the database level?

Based on the above and your own research of RDBMS (Relational Database Management Systems) vs NoSQL systems, you should then decide on which specific implementation of a system you want to use. E.g. PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, SQL Server are some options of RDBMS. MongoDB and DynamoDB are some NoSQL options. Note as long as you stick to a mainstream implementation, they're all rather equal in ability to solve problems and performance. (FWIW, my preference is RDBMS implementations and I think SQL Server and PostgreSQL are pretty awesome.)

Finally after you decide on a database implementation you should research "importing JSON file into *[insert database implementation name]*".